# Can I automate a card game (front-end) and back-end to deal card

Tags: cypress

I have a program I need to automate using cypress where I need to deal card (using front-end) and deal card to the front-end user, i.e automating on 2 different browsers/tab and switching between them.

I would need to switch between (Parent Tab) and (Child Tab) back-and-forth to achieve my goal. Is there any way around this please?

I found this code `cy.invoke('removeAttr', 'target')`, but it would not work for me in this case.

I have tried it and I am unable to complete the test using it.

Answer (score 1):

If the back-end is dealing the cards, you don't need two tabs to run the test.

You can mock the back-end using [cy.intercept()](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/intercept) commands. That way you can control the flow of data, and test the logic of the front-end.

Since your question is not specific, I cannot give you exact examples, but this is how I imagine it might go:

```js
cy.intercept('**/api/deal-a-card', { card: "ace-of-spades" })  // reply with a specific card

cy.get('button').contains('Deal').click()

cy.contains('Flush!').should('be.visible')
```